# How to flush registry files?

Tags: windows, transactions, filesystems, registry

In Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008R2 was introduced filesystem transactions.
Since that versions, I can't flushing registry files. I mean files that situated in Windows\System32\Config. For example file SYSTEM. 
The problem is that after some changes in regitry, windows doesn't update registry files. It happens only on system shutdown. 
I need to flush this files early, before the time when I starting to do a snapshot. It's important because I need a "fresh" version of this files after changes at the moment when I doing snapshot.
FlushRegistryKey, FlushFileBuffers and work with filesystem transaction does not help me. 
Have you any idea how to do this?

Comment: I believe you should be either using RegSaveKey or the Volume Shadow Copy Service, depending on context.